# How to cancel message in CallWndProc hook

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, hook

I am trying to hook the `CallWndProc` by `SetWindowsHookEx`. I would like to cancel the CallWndProc in specific case, but I have no idea how to do that. With `GetMsgProc` hook, I can use `pMsg->wParam = PM_REMOVE;` to eat the message and it is working perfect,but not for `CallWndProc`.

Any one know about this?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to achieve is not possible.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644975.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The `CallWndProc` hook procedure can examine the message, *but it cannot
>   modify it*. After the hook procedure returns control to the system, *the
>   message is passed to the window procedure*.